# Cobertura still tracks already deleted files

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, code-coverage, cobertura

I've deleted a subproject from my Maven parent project.

Now when I run `cobertura:cobertura` on the parent project, the classes that are already gone are still listed in the coverage report on our [Jenkins CI](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

The whole Maven command looks like this

```
cobertura:clean clean cobertura:cobertura
```

`forceMojoExecution` is also set to `true` in the parent's POM.

Why is Cobertura still tracking the already deleted files? I'm sure that they are no longer in the SVN, from where Jenkins obtains the sources.

I'm using Cobertura in version 2.5.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They seem to be in the build directory of Jenkins. Open your job in Jenkins and goto `Workspace` and select `Wipe Out Workspace`.